# modifying opengl (es 2.0) shader

Tags: android, opengl-es, shader

I have a (fragment) shader which is supposed to be modified during runtime (change one line of code). According to the [opengl docu](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glUseProgram.xml) it should be possible to modify attached shader objects. Is anyone aware of an example doing that? Detaching and deleting the old shader and creating, compiling and attaching the new shader to an existing program does not work (it compiles and links, but gives an GL_INVALID_OPERATION somewhere during drawing). [on android, GLSurfaceView]

Comment: Could you explain why it isn't sufficient to have logic in the shader to do different things based on the input you give it?

Comment: Basically, the user can provide a (arbitrary complex) arithmetic expression which is then used in the shader, e.g. sin(x), sin(x)*x and so on. This expression may change during runtime.